EarthEngine: how to sample pixels returning pixel geometry, not points
I would like to sample pixels within a given region, and extract the sampled pixel as a polygon. This will be used for ground-truthing at the polygon level.
I thought Image.sample would be the perfect function for it:

Samples the pixels of an image, returning them as a FeatureCollection.

But unfortunately this description is a bit misleading, as setting geometries: true will actually return points, not polygons (If true, adds the center of the sampled pixel).
So, how can I extract the polygon of the sampled pixel, not only its center? Should I manually transform the output of Image.sample? Or use another function?
var image = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4');

// Region to sample.
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-110.006, 40.002],
    [-110.006, 39.999],
    [-109.995, 39.999],
    [-109.995, 40.002]]], null, false);

// Show region on the map.
Map.centerObject(region);
Map.addLayer(ee.FeatureCollection([region]).style({"color": "00FF0022"}));

var samples = image.sample({
  region: region,
  numPixels: 5,
  geometries: true,
});

Map.addLayer(samples);


This seems to do the trick:
var projection = image.projection()
var polygons = samples
  .map(function (sample) {
    return ee.Image(1)
      .clip(sample.geometry())
      .reproject(projection)
      .reduceToVectors()
  })
  .flatten()

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d329d33721386fcf7e2bdd3c3d393d45

wow, very elegant solution, thanks a lot!

By using coveringGrid method it also works.
var proj_image = image.projection();

var grid_region = samples.geometry().coveringGrid(proj_image);

Map.addLayer(grid_region, {}, 'region grid');

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a5cddef29e9b00e428bc2704756f80cf
This is the result:

